# How to find the kth min element in a hashmap

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to find the kth min element in hash map, assumed it is a perfect hash map. How can I do that with good time complexity?
Any thoughts will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: About all you can do is scan through the table linearly. If you need ordering, consider using `std::map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your hash isn't changing often, I'd do a linear copy of the whole thing into a `vector` and then `std::nth_element` that (keeping a `dirty` flag so you regenerate the vector when needed).